# Can the Creality Digital Spool Holder be changed to trigger measurement externally and use the spool weight in OctoPrint?

Tags: creality-ender-3, octoprint, creality, spool

Did anyone try to disassemble the official Creality Digital Spool Holder and to make adjustments to access to the data and to trigger measurement, for the purpose of using and showing the remaining spool weight in OctoPrint?

I like the design but you have to manually push, wait a few seconds for the spool to set to 0, then weight the spool and it will only show for a few seconds on the screen, while not being able to communicate that data anywhere.

[image: Creality Digital Spool Holder]

Comment: The community is not that praising about this sensor. The weight is including the spool itself and it shuts down after 20 seconds. An interface with the main controller board would be cool though. It would require some calculations by the controller to determine the weight loss and posssibly an interface to determine the spool empty weight. I wonder if there are similar projects done by the community; does the question leave room for custom engineered solutions?

Comment: Absolutely room for custom, that was the point of my question. Preferably to hack this spool, but self build is an option too, like: I basically want to achieve this with that spool: https://github.com/dieki-n/Octoprint-Filament-Scale and https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/filament_scale/. What are the cons, why isn't the community praising this spool holder?